# ListBox.Items.Reverse() doesn't seem to work?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox, reverse

I have a `ListBox` which I am adding a varying amount of `StackPanel`s to, however I need these items to appear in reverse order in the `ListBox`.

I have tried using:

```
listBox.Items.Insert(0, stackPanel);
```

However this seems to only work when adding 1 `StackPanel` to the `ListBox`. When I add more than one I get an error which reads `invalid parameter`.

So I have resorted to:

```
listBox.Items.Add(stackPanel);
listBox.Items.Reverse();
```

However using `.Reverse();` doesn't seem to reverse the order of the `ListBox`?

I have also tried adding the `StackPanels` to a `List<StackPanel> list = new List<StackPanel>()` and used `list.Reverse();` however this doesn't seem to reverse the items either?

Does anyone know why the items won't reverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is actually an extension method comes from Linq. It doesn't actually modify the original collection, but returns a new set of items that represents the original set, in reverse order.

You're right that you can add only one item at time with `Insert`, but add multiple items in at once simply by calling it multiple times:

```
listBox.Items.Insert(0, stackPanel1);
listBox.Items.Insert(0, stackPanel2); // inserts stackPanel2 before stackPanel1
listBox.Items.Insert(0, stackPanel3); // inserts stackPanel3 before stackPanel2
```

Or if possible, just add them in reverse order:

```
listBox.Items.Add(stackPanel3);
listBox.Items.Add(stackPanel2);
listBox.Items.Add(stackPanel1);
```

You might also try reversing the items after you've added them, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count / 2; i++)
{
    var tmp = listBox.Items[i];
    listBox.Items[i] = listBox.Items[listBox.Items.Count - i - 1];
    listBox.Items[listBox.Items.Count - i - 1] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: The only trouble is that each stackPanel is generated due to a directory and files in IsolatedStorage, so I do not know how many of them there will be. I am using a foreach() statement to retrieve the information and apply to a stackPanel which is added to the listBox.

Comment: and just to clarify the problem with `listBox.Items.Insert(0, stackPanel)` is not that it can't add more than 1 item at a time, but if I use the command more than once it brings up an error which is mentioned above

Comment: @user2696648 When you're trying to add the second stackPanel, is it a new instance or not? Also how exactly do you try to 'add more than 1 item at a time'? What does the call look like?

Comment: When I am trying to add the second stackPanel it is a different stackPanel.

Comment: And I'm just saying that I'm not trying to add more than one stack panel at a time, thats what you said in your post which you have seem to misunderstood.       I am saying that when I try to add another object using the `Insert` method after using it previously an error comes up saying `invalid parameter`

Comment: @user2696648 But are you saying that calling `Add` works fine (ignoring `Reverse`), it just adds the items in the opposite order of what you want?

Comment: Yes. `.Add` works fine however using `.Insert` brings up an error if used more than once.

Comment: The specific error is: `System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=The parameter is incorrect. 
  StackTrace:
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodPack(IntPtr objectPtr, String methodName, Object[] rawData)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_Insert[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection1 collection, Int32 index, Object value)
` (this isn't the full error, it was too long to fit in the comment, however the rest of the error was much of the same).

Comment: Why not do `ListBox.Items = ListBox.Items.Reverse();`?

Comment: @Harrison Because the `Items` property isn't settable and even if it were, the return value from `Reverse` isn't an `ItemCollection`.

Comment: @user2696648 Well, unless there's a bug in the framework (which I doubt), that doesn't make a whole lot of sense. There are only two parameters it could be complaining about, the index or the `stackPanel`, and if you're saying that `Add` works, then it must be the index--but adding at index 0 *should* always be safe. I'm not that familiar with the Windows Phone framework, but there's got to be something more going on. Could you share more of your code?

Comment: @p.s.w.g that `if()` statement you added to the answer worked a treat. Thanks for your help :).